# No output when in run Line counting

Tags: c

When i run the line counting code in the C programming language book, i do not get any output.ie nothing is returned that reflects the number of lines. The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
//This program counts lines in its input
//
int main() {

    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar())!= EOF )
        if (c ==  '\n')
            ++nl; //nl = nl +1
    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

The output is below:

```
/home/xxx/xxxx/lineCounting1/cmake-build-debug/lineCounting1
line1
line2
line3
line4
^D

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I use ctrl+D to stop the execution and get an output. But nothing (except ^D is returned). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @RaulSauco It's defined as `int getchar(void)` in the POSIX standard. You need it to return an int as testing for `EOF` requires an int.

Comment: I just checked, and you are right, the return type is `int`, sorry about the mislead

Comment: `iostream` is C++, but your code is (mostly) C.  Since you've used a C tag, presumably you intend your code to be completely C.  Drop the iostream, or tag this C++

Comment: I tried it on my machine and it works fine. Do note that ^D needs to be on a separate line for it to see it

Comment: Try adding a newline before the `%d` as well as after it.  My suspicion is that the terminal echoing the `^D` is overwriting the `printf()` output.  Or try entering 100 or more lines of input so that 3 or more digits are printed.  Or use `printf("Number of lines: %d\n", nl);`.  If you can control the terminal attributes with `stty`, try using `stty -echoctl` to suppress the echoing of `^D`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a C program so we have to include stdio.h instead of iostream.

in the main we have declared 2 variables 
data type of variable name "c" should be "char" and nl is a counter which is currently set to 0.

getchar() is a library function which takes only the first character of of the string.
we are assigning the value of getchar to the c. and traversing it till end of file (EOF).
if condition is true then we are entering into the while.
there is a if condition inside the while which states that if(c == '\n') then incrementing the counter (nl) and displays the count.

code will be look like this but still it won't work because it is entering into the infinite loop
we have to assign something to the variable c.

```
`#include<stdio.h>
 //This program counts lines in its input
 int main()
 {
   char c;
   int nl;
   nl = 0;
   printf("Enter the character\n");
   while((c = getchar())!= EOF )
   {
     if (c ==  '\n')
     {
       ++nl; //nl = nl +1
       printf("%d\n", nl);
     }
   }
 }`
```